# Erro ao ler arquivo de texto linha a linha

Tags: c#, .net

Estou tentando ler um arquivo muito grande linha a linha e adicionando em uma lista, porém quando chega em um determinado ponto recebo um erro: `System.OutOfMemoryException`

Existe alguma forma de ler este arquivo todo em uma única só vez?

```
while ((line = trPlaces.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var htmlLine = line.Split('\t');

    try
    {
        var newPlace = new Place
        {
            Id = htmlLine[0],
            Name = htmlLine[2],
            IsoCountry = htmlLine[8],
            Latitude = htmlLine[4],
            Longitude = htmlLine[5],
            Admin1 = htmlLine[10].Length == 1 ? "0" + htmlLine[10] : htmlLine[10],
            Admin2 = htmlLine[11],
            PlaceType = htmlLine[7],
            AlternativeNames = htmlLine[3].Split(',')
        };

        if(listPlaces1.Count< 4000000)
        {
            listPlaces1.Add(newPlace);
        } else
        {
            listPlaces2.Add(newPlace);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção para ler o arquivo todo de uma vez e carregá-lo em um array é:

```
var arrLinhas = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Desenv\Texto.txt");
```

Uma sugestão para poupar memória seria **não** carregar todos os objetos na lista de uma vez. Você poderia criar uma classe para instanciar os objetos apenas quando eles forem utilizados.

Por exemplo:

```
public class PlaceFactory
{
    private string[] _places;

    public PlaceFactory(string filepath)
    {
        _places = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);  
    }

    public Place ObterPlace(int index)
    {       
        var htmlLine = _places[index].Split('\t');

        var place = new Place()
        {
            Id = htmlLine[0],
            Name = htmlLine[2],
            IsoCountry = htmlLine[8],
            Latitude = htmlLine[4],
            Longitude = htmlLine[5],
            Admin1 = htmlLine[10].Length == 1 ? "0" + htmlLine[10] : htmlLine[10],
            Admin2 = htmlLine[11],
            PlaceType = htmlLine[7],
            AlternativeNames = htmlLine[3].Split(',')
        };          

        return place;
    }
}

class App
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var placeFactory = new PlaceFactory(@"C:\Desenv\Texto.txt");

        Place place;

        place = placeFactory.ObterPlace(2);
        place = placeFactory.ObterPlace(0);
    }
}
```